# Making an array in the Table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, arrays

So we have an Table and there is an array which we wish to have it in the Table:

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,amsmath,amssymb,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,floatfix]{revtex4}
\begin{document}



\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{|c ||c| c| c| c|}  
 \hline
$d$ \; & \;  $Z$  & \; $UZ1$ & \; $UZ2$ & \; $U$\\  
               \; & \;   & \;       \;   & \;       \;   & \;   \\ \hline        
$d=1$    \; & \; $S_1=\int x_1{}^2$,    & \;  $Y_3=\int y_3{}^2$,       \;   & \;       \;   & \;  \\
              \; & \;  $S_2=\int x_2{}^2$  & \;   $G_4=\int g_4{}^2$    \;   & \;    \;   & \;   \\   \cline{2-5}           
              \; & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{$S1, S2, S3, \dots$ }  \\   \hline    
$d=2$       \; & \;   & \;       \;   & \;     \;   & \;   \\
                  \; & \;   & \;       \;   & \;    \;   & \;   \\   \hline    
 \end{tabular}
\caption{}
\end{table}


 $$
 \left\{ 
 \begin{array}{ll} 
 S_1=\int x_1{}^2,\\
 S_2=\int x_2{}^2 
  \end{array}  \right.
 $$



\end{document}
```

We have the array outside the Table I:

[image]

> **Question:** What we wish is that to put this array form:

```
$$\left\{ 
     \begin{array}{ll} 
     S_1=\int x_1{}^2,\\
     S_2=\int x_2{}^2 
      \end{array}  \right.
     $$
```

into the table, which **a single array exactly joins the two command lines** $S_1=\int x_1{}^2$, $S_2=\int x_2{}^2$ together inside the table. How to do that?

While we keep $Y3$ and $G_4$ separated not joined by another array.

Comment: argggg all those `\;` came back:-) and the `[!h]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more compact code, with the `cases` and `matrix*` environments. In addition, as I don't like too small integrals, I used the `medint` switch from the  `nccmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{booktabs,mathtools, nccmath}
\def\mint{\medint\int}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% Stretch out the tabular
\[ \begin{array}{*{5}{c}}
  \toprule
   d & Z & UZ1 & UZ2 & U \\
  \midrule
  d = 1 & \begin{cases}
    S_1 = \mint x_1{}^2, \\[3pt]
    S_2 = \mint x_2{}^2
  \end{cases} & \begin{matrix*}[l]Y_3 = \mint y_3{}^2, \\ G_4 = \mint g_4{}^2\end{matrix*} \\
\addlinespace
      & \multicolumn{4}{l}{ S1, S2, S3, \dots } \\[0.5\normalbaselineskip]
 d = 2 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing fancy about putting an `array` inside a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% Stretch out the tabular
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}  
  \toprule
  $d$ & $Z$ & $UZ1$ & $UZ2$ & $U$ \\
  \midrule
  $1$ & \raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}{$\biggl\{$}$\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}l@{}}
    S_1 & {}= \int x_1{}^2, \\
    S_2 & {}= \int x_2{}^2
  \end{array}$ & $\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}l@{}}
    Y_3 & {}= \int y_3{}^2, \\
    G_4 & {}= \int g_4{}^2
  \end{array}$ \\
      & \multicolumn{4}{l}{$S1, S2, S3, \dots$} \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  $2$ \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you must "keep *Y<sub>3</sub>* and *G<sub>4</sub>* ... not joined by another `array`", the following produces the exact same output (with proper alignment of *Y<sub>3</sub>* and *G<sub>4</sub>*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% Stretch out the tabular
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}  
  \toprule
  $d$ & $Z$ & $UZ1$ & $UZ2$ & $U$ \\
  \midrule
  $1$ & \smash{\raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}{$\biggl\{$}$\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}l@{}}
    S_1 & {}= \int x_1{}^2, \\
    S_2 & {}= \int x_2{}^2
  \end{array}$} & $\phantom{G_4}\mathllap{Y_3} = \int y_3{}^2,$ \\
    & & $G_4 = \int g_4{}^2\phantom{,}$ \\
      & \multicolumn{4}{l}{$S1, S2, S3, \dots$} \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  $2$ \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: OP asked "While we keep $Y3$ and $G_4$ separated not joined by another array."  (which is why the alignment is worse in my image:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Done... sorry, it didn't seem reasonable.

Comment: It's not:-) (actually OP may have just meant that Y_3/G_4 were not to be braced, so perhaps you should put it back

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,amsmath,amssymb,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,floatfix]{revtex4}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{8pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c ||c| c| c| c|}  
 \hline
$d$  &   $Z$  &  $UZ1$ &  $UZ2$ &  $U$\\  
                &    &           &           &    \\ \hline        
$d=1$     &  
\smash{\raisebox{-10pt}{$
 \left\{ 
 \begin{array}{ll} 
 S_1=\int x_1{}^2,\\
 S_2=\int x_2{}^2 
  \end{array}  \right.
$}}
   &   $Y_3=\int y_3{}^2$,          &           &   \\[7pt]
               &   &    $G_4=\int g_4{}^2$       &        &    \\   \cline{2-5}           
               & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{$S1, S2, S3, \dots$ }  \\   \hline    
$d=2$        &    &           &         &    \\
                   &    &           &        &    \\   \hline    
 \end{tabular}
\caption{}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach.

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,amsmath,amssymb,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,floatfix]{revtex4}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{%       %% code stolen from egreg
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \strut#1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{8pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c ||c| c| c| c|}
 \hline
$d$  &   $Z$  &  $UZ1$ &  $UZ2$ &  $U$\\ \hline
\head{$d=1$}     &
\head{$
 \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 S_1=\int x_1{}^2,\\
 S_2=\int x_2{}^2
  \end{array}  \right.
$}
   &   \head{$Y_3=\int y_3{}^2$,\\[7pt] $G_4=\int g_4{}^2$ }          &           &   \\\cline{2-5}
               & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{$S1, S2, S3, \dots$ }  \\   \hline
$d=2$        &    &           &         &    \\
                   &    &           &        &    \\   \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And another:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,amsmath,amssymb,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,floatfix]{revtex4}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{%       %% code stolen from egreg
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \strut#1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{8pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c ||c| c| c| c|}
 \hline
$d$  &   $Z$  &  $UZ1$ &  $UZ2$ &  $U$\\ \hline
\raisebox{-1.5\height}{\head{$d=1$}}     &
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\head{$
 \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 S_1=\int x_1{}^2,\\
 S_2=\int x_2{}^2
  \end{array}  \right.
$}}
    &   $Y_3=\int y_3{}^2$,         &           &   \\[-1.25em]
&   &    $G_4=\int g_4{}^2$         &           &    \\   \cline{2-5} 
               & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{$S1, S2, S3, \dots$ }  \\   \hline
$d=2$        &    &           &         &    \\
                   &    &           &        &    \\   \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]